# How do I read output from tcpdump as quickly as it prints it to the terminal?

Tags: tcpdump

When running tcpdump on the command line, packets appear in realtime as they are received. However, when tcpdump is piped into anything, it resorts to buffered output. The `-l` and `-U` options are provided to allow configuration of this. However, I find that no matter what options I set, the result is never as fast as running from the raw CLI. I've tried Python with subprocess, tee, and even a Rust wrapper. Packets always appear to be output in batches.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that it is not the client (the reader) that processes them in batches?

Comment: It's certainly possible. I've tried disabling all buffering in my wrappers and it still doesn't work. Do you have a suggestion for a reliable way to test this?

Comment: Using `unbuffer` from the `expect` package seems to fix it. Not completely sure what that indicates

Comment: Really depends on your code... In many languages, I/O is buffered by default. I also see this as comment in the unbuffer source code: Use a pseudoterminal to circumvent the block buffering performed by the
   stdio library when standard output is redirected to a file or pipe. Also see https://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/: "if stdout is a terminal then buffering is automatically set to line buffered, else it is set to buffered" and "if stdin/stdout are connected to a terminal then default size = 1024; else size = 4096 "

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25548995/5164855) and the surrounding discussion for a solution and explanations of the issues.

Answer (score 1):

tcpdump now has `--immediate-mode`, which solved this problem for me. In order to get it to work I used it in conjunction with `-l`.

See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/229336/183448).

Comment: For your convenience: `tcpdump -Uni eth0 -w tcpdump-eth0.out --immediate-mode`